# How to create new columns from an existing column that contains lists in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have the below PySpark DataFrame, I would like to create new columns out of the transaction column using PySpark. I'm not sure how this can be done by using python and pyspark functions.

```
| id      | transaction                                        |
| ------- | -------------------------------------------------- |
| 06t84g  | [['T_BILL',0.99],['Z_BILL',0.33],['A_BILL',0.77]]  |
| 098t1g  | [['T_BILL',0.419],['Z_BILL',0.19],['A_BILL',0.137]]|
| 03z94f  | [['T_BILL',0.79],['Z_BILL',0.49],['A_BILL',0.317]] |
| 10yw22  | [['T_BILL',0.91],['Z_BILL',0.818],['A_BILL',0.457]]|
| 30r990  | [['T_BILL',0.193],['Z_BILL',0.69],['A_BILL',0.947]]|
```

Below is the desired DataFrame:

```
| id      |  transaction                                       |T_BILL|Z_BILL|A_BILL|
| ------- | -------------------------------------------------- | --- | ---- | ---- |
| 06t84g  | [['T_BILL',0.99],['Z_BILL',0.33],['A_BILL',0.77]]  |0.99 |0.33  |0.77  |
| 098t1g  | [['T_BILL',0.419],['Z_BILL',0.19],['A_BILL',0.137]]|0.419|0.19  |0.137 |
| 03z94f  | [['T_BILL',0.79],['Z_BILL',0.49],['A_BILL',0.317]] |0.79 |0.49  |0.317 |
| 10yw22  | [['T_BILL',0.91],['Z_BILL',0.818],['A_BILL',0.457]]|0.91 |0.818 |0.457 |
| 30r990  | [['T_BILL',0.193],['Z_BILL',0.69],['A_BILL',0.947]]|0.193|0.69  |0.947 |
```

I really appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `explode()` and `pivot()`.

```
data_ls = [
    ('06t84g', [['T_BILL',0.99],['Z_BILL',0.33],['A_BILL',0.77]]),
    ('098t1g', [['T_BILL',0.419],['Z_BILL',0.19],['A_BILL',0.137]])
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'trans'])

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('trans_explode', func.explode('trans')). \
    select('id', 
           func.col('trans_explode').getItem(0).alias('bill_name'), 
           func.col('trans_explode').getItem(1).alias('bill_amt')
           ). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('bill_name', values=['T_BILL', 'Z_BILL', 'A_BILL']). \
    agg(func.first('bill_amt')). \
    show()

# +------+------+------+------+
# |id    |T_BILL|Z_BILL|A_BILL|
# +------+------+------+------+
# |06t84g|0.99  |0.33  |0.77  |
# |098t1g|0.419 |0.19  |0.137 |
# +------+------+------+------+
```

The `explode()` will create separate rows for each bill list. We can then use that to create 2 columns - one for the name, and another for the amount. Finally, we can just `pivot()` the name column created in the last step. If the array column is also required, we can add that to the `select()` and `groupBy()` statements.

---

Per OP's comment, if the `transaction` field is not an array column but an array in string format, we can first parse the string to create an array and then use the aforementioned code on the resulting array column.

```
data_ls = [
    ('06t84g', '''[['T_BILL',0.99],['Z_BILL',0.33],['A_BILL',0.77]]'''),
    ('098t1g', '''[['T_BILL',0.419],['Z_BILL',0.19],['A_BILL',0.137]]''')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id', 'trans'])

# parse the string to create an array
def parse_string_array(strarr):
    import json

    return json.loads(strarr.replace('\'', '\"'))

# use an UDF for pyspark transformation
# this parses the numbers as strings
# so the user can cast it to required format when required later
parse_string_array_udf = func.udf(parse_string_array, ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('trans_arr', parse_string_array_udf(func.col('trans'))). \
    withColumn('trans_explode', func.explode('trans_arr')). \
    select('id', 
           func.col('trans_explode').getItem(0).alias('bill_name'), 
           func.col('trans_explode').getItem(1).alias('bill_amt')
           ). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('bill_name', values=['T_BILL', 'Z_BILL', 'A_BILL']). \
    agg(func.first('bill_amt')). \
    show()

# +------+------+------+------+
# |    id|T_BILL|Z_BILL|A_BILL|
# +------+------+------+------+
# |06t84g|  0.99|  0.33|  0.77|
# |098t1g| 0.419|  0.19| 0.137|
# +------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: cannot resolve 'explode()' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;

Comment: @AndonShkurti can you share the data types of the input columns? it seems your `transaction` field is not an array column as opposed to what is shared in the example in your question.